# Plot Zoom with R

Tags: r, ggplot2, zooming

Good morning,
I have to zoom in the following plot.

```
times=data.frame("Times"=c(sample(seq(0, 1, 0.01),1000, replace = TRUE), sample(c(40:70), 500, replace = TRUE)), 
                 "Estimator"=rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each=500))

library(ggmagnify)#GitHub library
library(ggplot2)
library(PupillometryR)
times%>%
ggplot() +
  aes(x =Estimator ,
      y = Times) +
  geom_point(aes(color = Estimator),
             position = position_jitter(w = .15),
             size = 0.5,
             alpha = 0.15) +
  geom_boxplot(width = .24,
               outlier.shape = NA,
               alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_flat_violin(position = position_nudge(x = .2),
                   trim = TRUE, 
                   alpha = 1, 
                   scale = "width")  +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#FC4E07"))+
  coord_flip()+geom_magnify(aes(from = Estimator != "A" | Estimator == "B"),  to = c(1, 2, 20, 30), 
                            shape = "ellipse", shadow = F)
```

The result is:

[image]

This code zoom from "A" to "B" but i'd like to zoom in all the estimator "A" and "B". In other words I wouldn't want that the boxplot was cuted in the zoom. I try also with facet_zoom() but the result is even wrose.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you please add `set.seed()` ?

Comment: While there's probably a technical solution, wouldn't it be easier on the viewer to keep the two purposes (a = comparing estimators, b = illustrating within-estimator distribution in no less than three different ways) separated? Like with (a) three plain old boxplots and (b) box/density/etc in a `facet_wrap`ped layout so that each estimator has its own appropriate `free_x` scale?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are after? Possibly a matter of adjusting the parameters of the call to `ggmagnify`.

```r
set.seed(123)

times=data.frame("Times"=c(sample(seq(0, 1, 0.01), 1000, replace = TRUE), 
                           sample(c(40:70), 500, replace = TRUE)), 
                 "Estimator"=rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 500))

library(ggmagnify)#GitHub library
library(ggplot2)
library(PupillometryR)

times |> 
  ggplot() +
  aes(x =Estimator ,
      y = Times) +
  geom_point(aes(color = Estimator),
             position = position_jitter(w = .15),
             size = 0.5,
             alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_boxplot(width = .24,
               outlier.shape = NA,
               alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_flat_violin(position = position_nudge(x = .2),
                   trim = TRUE, 
                   alpha = 1, 
                   scale = "width") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#FC4E07")) +
  coord_flip() +
  geom_magnify(from = c(0.5, 3, -1, 2),  
               to = c(0.5, 3,  10, 30), 
               shape = "ellipse",
               shadow = F)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-06-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>